# Illegal XML Character - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services

> Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   XML parsing: line 931, character 10, illegal xml character

Is there a way to eradicate the illegal xml characters, as I keep getting thrown this error when I run the code below?

```
SELECT 
    ReportPath = C.Path  
    ,CAST(CAST(C.content AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS reportXML 
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog AS C
WHERE C.Type = 2
```

Comment: You'll need to use `REPLACE`, to remove the characters; which means converting to a `varchar(MAX)`, first, performing the `REPLACE`, and then converting to `xml`.

Comment: Possibly the illegal characters are perfectly legal ones, such as multi-byte characters in UTF-8 encoded XML getting mangled?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Is there a way to decipher whether they are illegal or not ? If the former, how would I go about this

Comment: @user3396351 You would have to inspect the specific ReportServer.dbo.Catalog.Content value that is giving you that error. Try dumping the problem value to disk and checking it with an XML editor or a Hex Editor.

Comment: @user3396351, Just to complement ALwaysLearning2 suggestion. After saving your XML as a file on the file system, you can try to open it in any Internet browser. It will show any  issue with illegal characters.